# Json deserialize in c#: json string with "1", "2", "3" (continious numbering)

Tags: c#, web, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have the following Json string returned from an API:

```
{
"1":{"key":"value", "key2":"value2"},
"2":{"key":"value", "key2":"value2"},
"3":{"key":"value", "key2":"value2"}
}
```

The numbering can go up to move than 10.000.

I use Json.Net for deserializing. Usually I declare a class with the properties key and key2 and make it a list. Then i deserialize with JsonConvert.Deserialize(...) and it works fine.

But how do I handle the numbering? I cannot create > 10.000 properties to hold the values.

Best regards
Morten

Comment: Even if marked as duplicate, the other answer was really difficult to find. I think I will leave this question here with a reference to the other question. The problem domain for the two questions also differs: Illegal identifies versus correct property structure for deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary` to deserialize your json

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, AClass>>(JsonConvert);


public class AClass
{
    public string key { set; get; }
    public string key2 { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you :-)